# Text box entered date should be in dd/MM/yyyy while creating date object using Jscript

Tags: javascript

`enter code here`Suggest me on this..
While **creating Date ref(java script)**, text box value should be treated as **dd/MM/yyyy** format..

```
function myFunction1(a)
{
       //Here the input format should be dd/MM/yyyy...
       //But Date ref taking it as MM/dd/yyyy
       var x=new Date(a);

       alert(x);

    if(x>new Date())
    {
    alert("Wrong date");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Success");
    }
}

----
<input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" />
<input name="buttonExecute" onClick="myFunction1(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Comment: You want to validate user input into a date field to dd/mm/yyyy? Please show some code?

Comment: please look it once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dateString = document.getElementById('<textboxid>').value;
var day   = parseInt(dateString.substring(0,2));
var month = parseInt(dateString.substring(3,5));
var year = parseInt(dateString.substring(6,10));
alert(new Date(year, month - 1, day));
```

To Validate Date, Use this code:

```
alert(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](\d{4})$/.test(dateString));
```

It will return true if the date is valid else return false.

Comment: Could also do `regex.exec(dateString)` and use values from result to create new date instead of substring

Comment: using date.js script(plugin) it is possible to wrap the format... but the text box value should be entered in MM/dd/yyyy format..